# Illegal instruction (core dumped) when import cv2 (Python)

Tags: python, opencv

I compiled OpenCV 2.4.3 using these flags:

```
-D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D WITH_TBB=ON
```

cmake (2.8.7) said that it might has problem detect Python lib (2.7.3), though the build is completed successfully.
However, below is the error when I importing cv2 in python

```
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

I had searched about this but didnt found anything related to OpenCV. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 Server 32bit if that matters.

Comment: Given that you have a core dump, you should be able to examine it with `gdb` to see what instruction caused the problem. That might help people work out what is going wrong.

Comment: Python just dumped **dlopen("/usr/local/lib/dist-packages/cv2.so")** then **Illegal instruction (core dumped)** comes

Answer (score 0):

I enabled AVX instructions during CMake configuration process, and have been having Illegal instruction exceptions for all OpenCV floating-point code. I am now recompiling OpenCV, with that option turned off. Only new CPUs support AVX, 2011 and later, and my i7-920 is from 2008.